# header('Location:') not redirecting

Tags: php, hosting, hostmonster

I have a login page which checks the `username` and the `password` and if the credentials provided by the user matches it sets the session and redirects the user, it works on my `godadd` hosting account but now i have shifted my hosting and suddenly it has stopped working, following is the code

```
if (count($result) > 0)
            {               
                $row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $userID = $row['userID'];               
                $firstName = $row['FirstName'];         

                $isActive = $row['IsActive'];

                if ($isActive == '1')
                {

                    $_SESSION['user'] = $firstName;     
                    //var_dump($firstName); //it gives me the right username                
                    //echo" - here";  //this also gets echoed
                    header("Location: http://google.com/"); //it just dies silently
                    exit;
                }
```

please help me find out where i went wrong

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: @jeroen no i dont have error reporting enabled

Comment: Start with that and see if it gives you any additional information.

Comment: @jeroen ok an out of context question do i have to obtain access to cpanel to turn on the error reporting? because at the moment i dont have the access just thr ftp, is there any short cut to that

Comment: No, just add `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to the top of your php script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: @jeroen my power went out anyway thank you very much for guiding me i turned on the error reporting and there it was some additional spaces in the file i was including ...i'll upvote you somewhere else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you don't output anything before the header tag. Since it was working before, I assume it's not an error where you are echo'n stuff before the call to header, and since you see no output, I assume it is outputting white-space. There are a few places where some whitespace and/or invisible characters can sneak into a file:

Put the cursor before your opening PHP tag (`<? or <?php`) and hit backspace a few times, then hit delete to delete the `<` and then retype the `<`. That will make sure there are no invisible characters being output to the browser before your headers.

Then go through any files that are included by that file, and do the same thing, as well as delete any `?>` that you have at the end of the file. If those files include any othe files repeat this on them.

Comment: @john Make sure you do the same thing in the file that you include with `require_once`, and any files that it includes/requires and so on. Then at the end of those files make sure there are no newlines being output. (The easiest way is to delete the `?>` if you have one. You don't need one at the end of a file.

Comment: If you use Notepad++ you also have to be careful not to encode the file with *UTF8 with BOM*

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. sry my power went out and after @ jeroen guided me to turn error reporting on i got the error that output already send at line so and so in the file i was including, it were some additional spaces so you were pretty close enough to the error thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

Are you outputting anything before calling header()?

If so, put ob_start() at the beginning of your script or make sure you're not echoing anything before header() is called

Comment: i am not echoing anything before the header

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `header()`, you must not `echo` anything prior to it.

Comment: i am not echoing anything before calling the header see its commented out in the question that was only to check if the db sonnection was successful, i am just starting the session and including a php file `require_once`

Answer (score 0):

add [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to the beginning of your script and add [`ob_end_flush();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) to the end of your script to avoid this issue.

ob_start(); will turn output buffering on and ob_end_flush(); will send the contents of the topmost output buffer and turn this output buffer off.